# Самосоединения: не понимаю почему порядок вывода таблиц не действует так, как должен

Tags: mysql, sql

1.SELECT *
FROM clown_info AS C1 INNER JOIN clown_info AS C2
ON C1.id = C2.boss_id;
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2.SELECT *
FROM clown_info AS C1 INNER JOIN clown_info AS C2
ON C2.id = C1.boss_id;
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не понимаю почему в первом запросе боссы выводятся слева, а их подчиненные справа, хотя все должно быть наоборот. ВО втором запросе я поменял `C1.id = C2.boss_id`  на `C2.id = C1.boss_id` и теперь боссы справа,а подчиненные слева, не понимаю почему так происходит, буду благодарен за объяснения))

Comment: А по моему все логично. в первом случае: Берем boss_id из таблицы C2 (которая в выводе справа), ищем этого босса в C1 и выводим (слева) то что в C1, т.е. id и имя босса

Comment: @Akina А порядок полей не менялся и пенять на порядок сканирования не надо. Там в условиях соединения другие поля. В первом случае из первой таблицы записи берутся по id, а во втором по boss_id, конечно это уже другие записи

Comment: по моему тоже все логично, первая выводится таблица `from .. as c1` в обоих случаях.

Comment: зы: а как по вашему должен? и почему вы думаете, что именно так должен.

Comment: Используйте не `*`, а явный список столбцов с указанием алиаса таблицы, и будет ровно то, что вам нужно

Comment: Благодарю всех за помощь)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все, понял. Как работает старый запрос `SELECT * FROM clown_info AS C1 INNER JOIN clown_info AS C2 ON C1.id = C2.boss_id;` я более-менее как-то понял открыв в разных терминалах две таблицы и визуализировав их соединение по условию в `ON`[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но я изменил немного условие в `ON`, поменяв `ON C1.id = C2.boss_id` на `C1.boss_id = C2.id` и все стало предельно понятно! Извиняюсь за пополнение стековерфлоу еще одним глупым вопросом.